# Mule ESB, "IN" operator within a JDBC transformer

Tags: java, mule, esb, mule-el

Let's imaging that I would like to pass a list into a JDBC transformer.

For instance, I create the list in a flow :

```
<scripting:transformer><scripting:script engine="groovy"><scripting:text>
    // Some calculations and stuff

    def single_quote_alias = "'"
    def listString = seasonMbIds.join("',' ")           
    return single_quote_alias + listString + single_quote_alias // now it's like:  '11','22','33' 
</scripting:text></scripting:script></scripting:transformer>
```

And then pass the list into another transformer:

```
<jdbc:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="XYZ" queryKey="someName" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
```

and here is the actual query:

```
<jdbc:query key="someName" 
                value="SELECT anID FROM aTable WHERE aField IN (#[payload:])" />
```

it gives me "out of bound index exception" :

```
Message               : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 (javax.script.ScriptException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Index: 0, Size: 0 (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException)
  java.util.ArrayList:635 (null)
2. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 (javax.script.ScriptException)
```

There are some escaping problem maybe. I used different delimiters and problem still exists ...

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What version are you using BTW? I see `#[payload:]` so I'm thinking 3.2 or older? Otherwise that would be `#[message.payload]`...

Comment: "3.3.1 Enterprise" ...

Comment: BTW, I made a custom transformer (in Java) to parse that query string and do stuff  with it.. I'm not quite sure why IN operator didn't work

Comment: This is a scripting error not a JDBC one: are you sure `seasonMbIds` contains something? Also this `.join("',' ")` will produce `'11',' 22',' 33'`. Finally, you're an EE user so you should use the JDBC EE connector, which is more capable than the CE one. Also consider contacting MuleSoft professional support, since you're using EE.

Comment: That space in join, was a mis-spell in stackoverflow editor. And yes, seasonMbIds is a normal list, containing elements. And I'm using JDBC with EE connector. 
Nevertheless, I solved it in other form. No need for calling support right now.. Thanks a lot of your answer, and attention :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Mule for more advanced JDBC stuff can be really, really painful because of the limited query formatting options. I know of two options you have: 1) write a script that uses your jdbc connector to perform the query, or 2) define a custom query strategy for your jdbc connector. Here is a simple hack that you can do to make that single query work with option 2 (will break all the other select queries though...):

include your custom Java class:

```
<jdbc:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MySQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc:sqlStatementStrategyFactory class="org.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.MySqlStatementStrategyFactory"/>
</jdbc:connector>
```

write your custom factory Java class:

```
package org.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy;

public class MySqlStatementStrategyFactory extends DefaultSqlStatementStrategyFactory {

  public MySqlStatementStrategyFactory()
  {
    super();
    selectSQLStrategy = new MySelectSqlStatementStrategy();
  }

}
```

Create your strategy class and copy the source code for the default select strategy from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-jdbc/3.4.0/org/mule/transport/jdbc/sqlstrategy/SelectSqlStatementStrategy.java)

replace the class definition in the copied source code:

```
public  class MySelectSqlStatementStrategy extends SelectSqlStatementStrategy
```

find the two lines that create the query result and replace with your own implementation, for example:

```
result = connector.getQueryRunnerFor(endpoint).query(connection, readStmt.replace("?", (String)params[0]),
      connector.getResultSetHandler());
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton..  I made a custom transformer (in Java) to parse that query string and do stuff with it..